# R Studio - How to insert characters in the middle of a string/vector at random location in data frame

Tags: rstudio, paste

I'm trying to insert special characters @,#,or $ in the middle (doesn't have to be in the middle, but in between) of a vector in a dataframe. For example, insert @ to into 12345 to be 12@345 or 123@45 or 1234@5.

This is what I have:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=c(123,234,223214), b=c(78941014,0123,45645), 
c=c(41,54524,56465))
> df
       a        b     c
1    123 78941014    41
2    234      123 54524
3 223214    45645 56465
```

I want something like this:

```
           a        b     c
1    12@3 7894@1014    41@
2    23@4      123 @ 54@524
3 22@3214    4564@5 56@465
```

I tried 
   `df8$a <- paste("@", df$a, sep="")` 
but it just add @ to the first character. I want it to be in between.

Thanks advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(a=c(123,234,223214), b=c(78941014,0123,45645),c=c(41,54524,56465))
df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df, as.character))
df.output <- data.frame(a = character(), b = character(), c = character() ,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


ncol <- ncol(df)
nrow <- nrow(df)

for (i in 1:ncol) {  
  for (j in 1:nrow) { 

    df.output[i,j]  <- sapply(Map(append, strsplit(as.character(df2[i,j]), ""), after = sample(1:nchar(df[i,j]), 1), "@"), paste, collapse = "")

  }  
}

df.output

        a         b      c
1    1@23 78941@014    41@
2    234@      123@ 5452@4
3 223@214    456@45 5646@5
```

You really can skip the df.output and use directly the df2 to update the values, but I wanted to show the solution in a clear way.